# Identify UIDocument uniquely

Tags: ios, uidocument

I'm working on a document based app with UIDocumentBrowserViewController. The app itself creates txt files which the user can edit and save.

I want to send those files to a companion app on an Apple Watch. The user can then read those on the watch. The UIDocument is read by my app and converted to be sent with WCSession.

The question is now: How can I uniquely identify an UIDocument?

I know I could make my own identifier by putting a UUID in the file name or at the end of each text file, but this is not the sweet solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apple recommends the UUID for a filename approach](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/ManageDocumentLifeCycle/ManageDocumentLifeCycle.html), but does mention that you can have the user change the display name after it is created.

> The UIDocument class assumes a correspondence between the filename of
>   a document and the document name (also known the display name). By
>   default, UIDocument stores the filename as the value of the
>   localizedName property. However, an application should not require a
>   user to provide the document filename or display name when he or she
>   creates a new document.
>
> For your application, you should devise some convention for
>   automatically generating the filenames for your new documents. Some
>   suggestions are:

- Generate a UUID (universally unique identifier) for each document,
  optionally with an application-specific prefix.
- Generate a timestamp (date and time) for each document, optionally with an application-specific prefix.
- Use a sequential numbering system, for example: “Notes 1”, “Notes 2”, and so on.

> For the document (display) name, you might initially use the document
>   filename if that makes sense (such as with “Notes 1”). Or, if the
>   document contains text and the user enters some text in the document,
>   you might use the first line (or some part of the first line) as the
>   display name.  **Your application can give users some way to customize
>   the document name after the document has been created**.

Comment: I think that would not work. If the user moves the file to another location or changes the name of the file in iCloud Drive the fileURL changes. Also the modification date would not work because every time it is updated the modification date changes as well...

Comment: @NicoS. Yea, that makes sense. Not familiar with using the watch, so had not considered that.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer, but however this is more for apps that can create a wrapper around the file name to hide it. In iCloud Drive the user always gets to see the raw file name. This is a solution as a mentioned in my question, but it is not the sweet solution ;)

Comment: @NicoS. Agreed, I am working on a project right now that also involves UIDocument, but we are not working with other devices (iCloud, yes - but a different developer). I could see creating a CoreData model that tracks the file & unique ID, but have not taken it any further then that.

Comment: All you're doing here is quoting the docs. And the docs you're quoting are old. I don't think they are very applicable now that the filename is user-facing thru the document browser / Files app. Hard to see how this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `URLResourceKey.documentIdentifierKey` ? This is a persistent identifier which tracks a document across renames and safe-saves.

Comment: [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlresourcekey/1412351-documentidentifierkey) say: "This property is not supported by all volumes." Do you by any chance know what kind of volumes are unsupported and what this would mean for the returned value?

Comment: If the volume is unsupported, I guess this will return an error? This works on APFS/HFS but won’t work on FAT or SMB. You can check the volume capabilities bit VOL_CAP_FMT_DOCUMENT_ID to know whether document tracking is supported. See man getattrlist to know how to check volume capabilities.